# Perl module WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS errors using example prgram as test

Tags: perl

I just imported WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS today that appeared to be successful using cpan WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS.   After the completion of the install/import,  I used the default example program as a test and received this error:

> 'phantomjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command
>   Question:  How do I fix this problem?

This error is coming from this line in the test program:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS->new(
    launch_arg => ['ghostdriver/src/main.js' ],
);
```

Here is the full code copied directly from the PhantomJS example code:

```
use strict;
use File::Spec;
use File::Basename 'dirname';
use WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS;
my $url = 'https://radioa1a.com/trop-40-vote/';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS->new(
    launch_arg => ['ghostdriver/src/main.js' ],
);

sub show_screen() {
   my $page_png = $mech->content_as_png();
    my $fn= File::Spec->rel2abs(dirname($0)) . "/screen.png";
    open my $fh, '>', $fn
    or die "Couldn't create '$fn': $!";
    binmode $fh, ':raw';
    print $fh $page_png;
    close $fh;




    #system(qq(start "Progress" "$fn"));
};

$mech->get($url);

show_screen;
```

The full error message from my Windows 10 command prompt window:

```
C:\Users\Bryon\Desktop\Perl>TestWebPage.pl
'phantomjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Selenium server did not return proper status at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 543.

C:\Users\Bryon\Desktop\Perl>
```

My environment:

1. Windows 10 64-bit
2. Strawberry Perl version:

   C:\Users\Bryon\Desktop\Perl>perl -v

   This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 2 (v5.30.2) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

   Copyright 1987-2020, Larry Wall

   Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
   GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

   Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
   this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
   Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.

Also, I see the PhantomJS module components in the C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\wWW\Mechanize\PhantomJS\

So how do I fix this issue?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Sounds like you need to install phantomjs and/or have it in your path.

Comment: Yes, you need the PhantomJS executable on your OS. But it's an abandoned software (since 2018). Better learn to code in javascript with chrome headless+puppeteer module. When you know the basics, it's not that hard to learn

Comment: Found an unofficial Python port: https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer (nothing for Perl). I don't recommend this specific way

Comment: Yes phantomjs is not being maintained anymore.  But I still use it :)

Comment: The module relies on the [`phantomjs`](https://phantomjs.org/) tool, which needs to be installed and in your PATH. Note that development of `phantomjs` was [abandoned](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344) two years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> XXXXX is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This error tells that there is no needed executable in your PATH.
Try to download actual PhantomJS executables for windows from [official site](https://phantomjs.org/download.html) and place it into folder from your PATH variable.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution and explanation.  I thought the module was a complete package and did not realize that PhantomJS was a standalong exe file that needed to be on my system in addion to the PhantomJS.pm cpan installation.   Thank you again for the clarification too.   Have a great day.